# How to attach a static external IP address to a google cloud compute instance using the CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, google-compute-engine

I want to create a google cloud compute instance with a static external ip address. I can do that if I manually do it with the console in the browser.

I have been looking through the documentation, I can't see an argument to create the static external IP address on creation using the CLI tools.

To create instances I have been using `gcloud compute instances create --zone us-central1-a --source-instance-template instance-template instance-node-1`

How do I attach a static external IP address to it using the CLI so that when I shut it down and  restart it, it will have the same IP address?

Comment: This takes multiple steps. First create the IP address: `gcloud compute addresses create IP_NAME --region=REGION` and then assign it to the instance `gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME --address IP_ADDRESS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get exactly you want with "--address" flag.

According to Google document, You can create a vm instance with static external IP address like below.

`gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME --address IP_ADDRESS`

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance) to get detailed information.